# Error running with more than 16 tasks MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated

Tags: c, mpi

I have this c code that calculates polynomial arrays, where I'm trying to run it from a cluster using MPI.

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int id;
  int n;
  int i, size, arraySize;
  double *vet, valor, *vresp, resposta, tempo, a[GRAU + 1];
  int hostsize;
  char hostname[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &hostsize);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n);

  if (id == 0) // Master
  {
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Bcast(&a, GRAU, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (size = TAM_INI; size <= TAM_MAX; size += TAM_INC)
    {
      tempo = -MPI_Wtime();
      for (int dest = 1; dest < n; ++dest)
      {
        int ini = 0;
        int fim = dest * size / (n - 1);
        int tam = fim - ini;

        MPI_Send(&ini, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&tam, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&x[ini], tam, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        ini = fim;
        fflush(stdout);
      }

      int total = 0;
      for (int dest = 1; dest < n; ++dest)
      {
        int ini_escravo;
        int tam_escravo;
        MPI_Recv(&ini_escravo, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&tam_escravo, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&y[ini_escravo], tam_escravo, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      }
      tempo += MPI_Wtime();
    }
  }
  else
  { // Slave
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Bcast(&a, GRAU, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (arraySize = TAM_INI; arraySize <= TAM_MAX; arraySize += TAM_INC)
    {
      int ini, tam;
      MPI_Recv(&ini, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&tam, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&x[0], tam, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      for (i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
        y[i] = polinomio(a, GRAU, x[i]);

      MPI_Send(&ini, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&tam, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&y[0], tam, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      fflush(stdout);
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The code works fine when I run using 16 tasks or less per node. If I try to run using 32 tasks (16 per node, with 2 nodes), I get the following message:

> [06:272259] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv [06:272259] *** reported
> by process [2965045249,0] [06:272259] *** on communicator
> MPI_COMM_WORLD [06:272259] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
> [06:272259] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator
> will now abort, [06:272259] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
> [07][[45243,1],31][btl_tcp.c:559:mca_btl_tcp_recv_blocking] recv(20)
> failed: Connection reset by peer (104)

Any idea about what I am missing here?

Comment: It looks like you should use `MPI_Scatterv()` and `MPI_Gatherv()` instead of send/recv. Because you use `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`, you might end up using `ini_escravo` from process 1, `tam_escravo` from process 2 and receive too much data in `y` from process 3.

Comment: But why it works in 1 node, 8 or 16 processes, and 32 process in 2 nodes doesnt?

Comment: In my homework i was assigned to use specifically Send and Recv, i assume the logic is working fine

Comment: I resolved using dest variable instead MPI_ANY_SOURCE at master result receiving, i'm not sure if it decreases the algoritm performance, but worked better than sequencial and 16 tasks

Comment: Your initial program had undefined dehavior, so when it produces correct results, it just means you were lucky.

Comment: Thank you Gilles, by your comment I understood what was the problem and solved it.